# List of JSON objects to controller

Tags: jquery, sql-server, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm still trying to understand how a list of JSON objects has to be send to a controller to save the data in a SQL server database table 'Invitees'.

An example would be very useful.

JSON:

```
[{Email :"e@g.com",Presence :"nodig"},{Email :"h@g.com",Presence :"gewenst"}]
```

Model:

```
public class Invitee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Presence { get; set; }
};
```

Controller: (model returns a null exeption, ModelState = true)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InviteeSave(List<Invitee> model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var db = new MainDbContext())
        {
            var dbInv = db.Invitees.Create();

            foreach (var inv in model)
            {
                dbInv.AppId = 35;
                dbInv.Email = inv.Email;
                dbInv.Presence = inv.Presence;

                db.Invitees.Add(dbInv);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong");
    }
    return Json(model);
}
```

jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("InviteeSave", "App")',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    accept: 'appication/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            alert("Met succes !");
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your AJAX request; the issue is in C#. What is `null` exactly? Place a breakpoint in the Action and step through it if need be.

Comment: Spelling error in `appication` (missing `l`)

Comment: Sorry for that.
In the controller 'model' returns a NULL exception

Comment: @StephenMuecke good eyes :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Spelling now OK, but error still occurs.

model seems to have no public members

Comment: Use `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Comment: I've changed 'accept' into 'contentType' but the NullReferenceException still occurs on model in "foreach (var inv in model)".

Comment: Use `data: JSON.stringify({ model: jsonData }),` - works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry You cannot send a Collection(List) of user defined types.
There is a work around.

Make the Controller Parameter Type as

> DataTable type of C#

then POST your Data via ajax. It works for me.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL/api/.....",
        data: {Email :"e@g.com",Presence :"nodig"},{Email :"h@g.com",Presence :"gewenst"},
    }).done(function( data ){ 
         console.log(data) 
 });
```

I have this working in my web app currently

EDIT :
You can Post List ; list of string to controller parameter too. then you can get your sort your data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can send collection of items to controller post action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InviteeSave(List<Invitee> model)
{
    //Your code goes here
}
```

JS:
//(url: should be actionname, controller in case you are using @Url.Action() or else simply give  url: '/controller/method/')

```
$.ajax({
            url: "InviteeSave",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ model: jsonData }),
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    alert("Met succes !");
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert('error' + 'Came here');
            }
        });
```

My view is

```
<form id="frmInvitee" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input type="submit" name="BtnSumbit" id="BtnSumbit" />
</form>
```

Post your view... It works for me ...